# How to Simulate subquery in MongoDB query condition

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's suppose that I have a product logs collection, all changes are being done on my products will be recorded in this collection ie :

```
+------------------------------+
| productId - status - comment |
| 1           0        ....    |
| 2           0        ....    |
| 1           1        ....    |
| 2           1        ....    |
| 1           2        ....    |
| 3           0        ....    |
+------------------------------+
```

I want to get all products which their status is 1 but hasn't became 2. In SQL the query would look something like :

```
select productId from productLog as PL1 
where 
   status = 1 
   and productId not in (
       select productId from productLog as PL2 where 
           PL1.productId = PL2.productId and PL2.status = 2
   )
group by productId
```

I'm using native PHP MongoDB driver.

Answer (score 1):

Well since the logic here on the subquery join is simply that exactly the same key matches the other then:

### Setup

```js
db.status.insert([
    { "productId": 1, "status": 0 },
    { "productId": 2, "status": 0 },
    { "productId": 1, "status": 1 },
    { "productId": 2, "status": 1 },
    { "productId": 1, "status": 2 },
    { "productId": 3, "status": 0 }
])
```

Then use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.status.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "status": { "$ne": 2 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$productId"
    }}
])
```

Or using map reduce (with a DBRef):

```js
db.status.mapReduce(
    function() {
        if ( this.productId.$oid == 2 ) {
            emit( this.prouctId.$oid, null )
        }
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return null;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
);
```

But again the SQL here was as simple as:

```sql
select productId
from productLog
where status <> 2
group by productId
```

Without the superfluous join on exactly the same key value

Comment: In my case productId contains a MongoDBRef value, and i cannot use it in $group operator.

Comment: @Rabi Well your question does not state that and if you looked here then you would easily find that you need `mapReduce` to access the `_id` of a DBRef. You should not be using `DBRef` anyhow as it is basically deprecated. Same principles apply though, there is "no join" required here.

Comment: I couldn't find that DBRef is deprecated in Mongo website even in PHP manual.

Comment: @Rabi mapReduce example added. Trust me. Move away from using `DBRef`.

Answer (score 0):

This mongo query above doesn't meet the requirements in question,
the result of the mongo-query includes documents with `productId=1`,
however the result of the SQL in question doesn't. Because in sample data: there exists 1 record with `status=2`, and `productId` of that document is 1.

So, assuming `db.productLog.insert` executed as stated above, you can use the code below to get the results:

```
//First: subquery for filtering records having status=2: 
var productsWithStatus2 = db.productLog .find({"status":2}).map(function(rec) { return rec.productId; }); 

//Second:final query to get productIds which there not exists having status=2 with same productId :
db.productLog.aggregate([ {"$match":{productId:{$nin:productsWithStatus2}}},{"$group": {"_id": "$productId"}}])  ;

//Alternative for Second final query:
//db.productLog.distinct("productId",{productId:{$nin:productsWithStatus2}}); 

//Alternative for Second final query,get results with product and status detail:
//db.productLog.find({productId:{$nin:productsWithStatus2}});
```